# Escaping in bash within perl

Tags: bash, perl, escaping

I'm running something in perl and have the following command, which deletes consecutive duplicate lines (only keeping one of them)

`system("sed -i '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!p; d' *[13579].csv");`

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated address regex`

I have a feeling it has to do with my escaping, but I'm not too certain as I am rather inexperienced with perl and bash. I know the dollar signs should be escaped, but what about the backslashes? Does anyone have a good resource they can point me to to learn more about escaping bash within perl? Thanks!

Comment: Escape the slashes \

Comment: @mkHun Not all of them right -- it currently looks like: `system("sed -i '\$!N; /^\\(.*\\)\\n\\1\$/!p; d' *[13579].csv")`. Does this look right?

Comment: If you need to escape things, you're doing it wrong: If you start a program (`sed`, in this case) by directly `exec`'ing an argv array, there is no shell, so nothing needs to be shell-escaped. Yes, that means you don't get globbing, but perl can do globbing itself.

Comment: I wouldn't call `sed` from `perl`, because `perl` can do everything `sed` can without a call out.

Comment: Not related to this issue, but you can use `uniq` instead of `sed` based approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting sed in Perl it can be fussy, there's a couple things you could do. The first would be to change the type of quotes you wrap around the command system is running and the sed pattern (flip outer to single, inner to double); the other option would be to escape the `\` characters in sed.

```
system('sed -i "$!N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!p;d" *filename');
```

Note: since your filename uses a special characters there might be escaping needed for that to work with globbing (eg. `*\\[13579].csv`); escaping would be something like this:

```
system("sed -i '$!N;/^\\(.*\\)\\n\\1\$/!p;d' *\\[13579].csv");
```

If your file name happens to include spaces then those would need escaping as well.

```
system("sed -i '$!N;/^\\(.*\\)\\n\\1\$/!p;d' *\\[12345]\\ \\[13579].csv");
```

`sed` would then find any files matching `*[12345] [13579].csv` and in-place edit them.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very informative and helpful. I'll keep this in mind moving forward.